# Azure and VS2017 subscription

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I found that with VS2017 it is available 50$/per month Azure credit. I have never worked with Azure before, but have a little experience with CloudFoundry. It seems a good chance for me to try Azure now. So, my question is what I can obtain with 50$/month? Is it enough for small ASP .NET Core web-site, database, some services into docker containers, just to play with these?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can play around these services.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/credit-for-visual-studio-subscribers/
Credit for use on a wide range of Azure services. Virtual Machines, Storage, SQL Databases, Containers, Cognitive Services, Functions, Data Lake, and much more.
Azure dev/test pricing helps your credit last longer.
Exclusive access to Windows 10 virtual machine images.
Easy sign-up. No credit card required.
No surprises. A spending limit protects you from overage charges. You can remove the spending limit when you’re ready.